# Too low efficiency with "0-30V 2mA-3A DC Regulated Power Supply unit with Continuously Adjustable Current Limiting Protection" PSU kit

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, linear-regulator

I ordered and assembled the kit (link and image added below). Everything works fine.

But as everybody knows, it requires a great heat sink for the regulator. The ordered unit costs less than $5, but it needs huge heat sink together with cooling fan, display and 24VAC power source.

I prepared everything. It works like a charm. But I measured the outlet power and output power of the kit:

OUTLET: 220V 25W
OUTPUT: 5V 0.5A 2.5W

10 times.

Why don't people just use cellphone charger with the limited current feature such as 500mA instead of this sophisticated circuit?

What's the point of current limiting power supply circuit?

** ADDED **

The product is here:

[image: photo of PSU kit components from AliExpress link below]

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/0-30V-2mA-3A-DC-Regulated-Power-Supply-DIY-Kit-Continuously-Adjustable-Current-Limiting-Protection-for/32904860329.html

It also has some PCB printings and description.

** UPDATE **

There're a bit of noisy comments posted following this question, but the only answer which helped is that:

> This circuit is linear voltage regulator which is less efficient than switching mode voltage regulator.

I know that very well, but missed that long time ago. Suddenly realized.

Comment: 1) unclear what the "regulated power supply" unit actually is. Include picture/schematic/datasheet etc. 2) Unclear what "OUTLET" means, is that on the device? 3) Unclear where "OUTPUT" comes from, OUTPUT is 5 V but elsewhere you mention 0 - 30 V? 4) "10 times?" How and what? What did you expect instead of 10 times and why? 5) "Why don't people just use cellphone charger " We do, to charge cellphones. A 0-30V supply isn't really designed for that so are you comparing apples to pears?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie , 1) I added link to the product. 2) OUTLET means power plug from the wall via 220VAC. 3) OUTPUT means the output with power meter attached from the power supply unit to the cellphone charging plug. 4) 220VAC 113.6mA = 25W, 5VDC 500mA = 2.5W. 5) Apple also has sugar which gives pleasure to the eater as pear does.

Comment: This kit also charges cellphone battery as normal cellphone charger does.

Comment: *OUTLET means power plug from the wall via 220VAC* Sure but the kit you show uses up to 30V DC as input, **not** 220 VAC. So sure, if you use an 1000W supply to power this board the 220V AC rating will be say 5A, 220V AC so even worse than what you quote. This KIT is a **linear regulator** so that's why it needs a large heatsink as it is inefficient **by design**. Cellphone chargers are **designed** to efficiently convert 220 V AC into 5 V DC. Your kit **is not**. Learn more by watching: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PISZsjNhq7I

Comment: @user58029: I've read through the comments and don't detect any anger. What I do sense and share is the frustration of trying to understand a badly written question. Your first sentence has random capitalisation and no verb so it's not clear what it is about. Another sentence "10 times" is not a full sentence. A folksy writing style may not be appropriate for a technical question. All the commenters were interested enough in your question to respond to you.

Comment: @Transistor , Some people still answer what exactly I wanted to know. I mentioned "EFFICIENCY" as the 1st parts of the question and, OUTLET: 220V 25W OUTPUT: 5V 0.5A 2.5W : 10 times. 2.5W * 10 times = 25W. Elementary school math. What's the problem? I'm not going to waste my time arguing here any more. Neither do you.

Comment: I'm not arguing. You are. I'm explaining. If you're not interested in improving your writing then that's your choice but please don't be surprised by the responses. Bye-bye.

Comment: That's why people are turning their back on electronics.stackexchange.Bye~bye~

Comment: @SamGibson added that photo of the product instead of PCB focused one next to that image in the store URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the power supply you have linked, is for it to be used in a laboratory/test bench environment. This is by no means a precision power supply.

The feature that it offers it is not efficiency, but control on the output voltage and current.

The reason for being able to adjust the current is so that the circuit you are testing is protected. If the current is exceeded, the over-current protection kick in, cutting off the power to the circuit.

To make an example, if you want to test a new circuit design, that could either be a PCB or a breadboard prototype, it is wise to limit the amount of current that can be delivered to this circuit, so that in the unfortunate case of a short circuit, or error in the design (and that happens a lot), the user will avoid seen the blue smoke, destroy the components in question, and get a warning light instead.

To address the efficiency of the power supply, this design, is a linear regulator, which means that the difference in voltage between the input and the output is dissipated in heat, hence the need to a large heatsink and fan.

The real limitation of this power supply, compared to a fully assembled one, is that there is no display to show, the output voltage, or the set current limit. With little knowledge, both of these can be added, including a nice enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a cell phone charger, it is a learning project.
People buy it to learn how a charging circuit works. Not to have a better charger.

It also can do 0-30V, something a cell phone charger won't.

Also it's 2.97 from China, what did you expect?

Comment: Also: since it can do 0 - 30 V it can be used as a "cheap bench supply" for hobbying and experiments. It is designed to be **cheap, easy, flexible** but not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a linear regulator, for the same output current the dissipation in the circuit increases as the output voltage is reduced.

As an example, assuming 24V DC input and current of 1.5A, an output voltage of 18V has a circuit dissipation of around 9W and an output power of 27W (75% efficiency), but an output voltage of 4V has a circuit dissipation of 30W and an output power of 6W (17% efficiency).

There is no point in comparing this circuit with a purpose-designed cellphone charger - this design deliberately sacrifices efficiency for versatility.

Answer (score 0):

Something else to think about.

> I prepared everything. It works like a charm.

Well, at 5 volts I'm sure it does. However, I'll pretty much guarantee that it will not put out 30 volts at 3 amps. A 24-volt AC input will have a peak voltage of about 34 volts, and the voltage across the 3300 uF cap will vary by about 5-6 volts over the course of a power cycle (it's called ripple). Then add another couple of volts of drop for the regulator circuit and the output at high voltage and current will not be remotely well-behaved. I'd be wary of using the circuit for anything greater than 24 volts output at high current.